# exponential stability of autonomous systems in dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider an autonomous ODE $$\dot x = f(x)$$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_0$ is an equilibrium point. I was wondering  if the following statement is true:

If all eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0)$ have negative real part, then $x_0$ is [exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems) stable.

Note that the above statement is obvious if we replace "exponentially" with "asymptotically ".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $x_{0}$ is exponentially stable. As far as I know, that is called linearization. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the linearization (Hartman–Grobman theorem) is about asymptotic stability, rather than exponential stability. Am I missing something?

Comment: It can also be noted that it only **locally** exponentially stable (not necessarily globally).

Comment: Check G.Teschl, ODE and Dynamical systems, page 199, theorem 6.10. Hope you find it helpful :)